# What was the societal wealth demographics when the major pyramids were built?

Tags: social-class, economy, demography

[All this talk about wealth distribution](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/22/opinion/kristof-a-failed-experiment.html?_r=1&) (1% of US Citizens etc. etc.) got me wondering about the wealth distribution in other periods of history when - let's call them - **great edifices** were built.

*E.g.* when the major pyramids were built, did '1% of the population' control as much wealth as the 'bottom 90%'?  Was the ratio even more exaggerated?

I suppose the question could be answered with the most accurate demographics from any civilization / empire period, where a major edifice was created (great wonder, 'multi-national infrastructure', etc).

---

Personally, I'm curious to understand the relationship between cultural projects and wealth distribution.

Comment: Having great capital leads to having greater capital (hence "capitalism"). But even 500 years ago the positive feedback loop of capital was of no importance whatsoever. It was important to have much land, vasals, and army. If you had money, great, but it didn't led you to have even more money; you had the money so you spent it and had less.

Comment: I don't believe the pyramids of Egypt attest to an unusual *distribution* of wealth for an ancient empire, but rather to the unusual *total* wealth available to the rulers of the lower Nile valley. Sometimes quantity has a quality all its own.

Comment: This is a little hard to answer as in ancient times the wealth **valuation** would have been an issue. How do you value being considered a god? (Pharaoh/Roman emperors). How do you value ability to declare war just to get more resources and slaves? You can't run Black-Shoales on *that* option. How do you value ability to sham-convict millions of people and get them to build Belomor-Canal for free? Money has a lot different meaning in today's world than 500+ years ago, as  kubanczyk said

Comment: Also, technically speaking, in many societies, 100% of everything everyone owned was ultimately the property of the Royal. So 100% was owned by them.

Comment: @DVK I hear you, regarding valuation.  Since our money is fiat *currency*, we are all natively-divorced from understanding that currency is a relative standard, just as you say, ***but** that something always drives it.  The wink of a demigod may be worth $1bn USD; but that's the going rate.  Since that demigod/demagogue controls the wink, most of the wealth is probably thus concentrated in less than 0.00001% of the society.

Comment: @kubanczyk you're right that land was, for many cultures, currency, and only the landed had actual wealth/capital.  Thus, serfs.  A land was richer for skilled usage == labor & tending.  So, though 'uncapitalized', wealth of the nation still was held through individuals of the nation / culture.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Every your word assures me we are not on the same page at all. "Wealth" and "currency" are terms that don't help with anything here, but very much contribute to  misunderstanding and useless debates.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to phrase either the question or the answer in meaningful terms. How much of the population had the legal right to own property?  In the absence of a meaningful market, what is "captial"?  And as @NewAlexandria says, "wealth" was based on land.  I don't think you can compare that to the modern world where wealth is based on capital which is traded freely in a market, and everyone has the legal right to own property.

Comment: Claiming that wealth accumulation didn't exist in the past because people didn't have money as the means to determine their wealth is fundamentally flawed.